# How to send Multiple parameters in passes function of custom validation rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am implementing a custom validation rule which should take another parameter with attribute and value in passes function of custom validation rule. As we implement Rule interface while writing custom validations, it does not allow us to add third parameter in passes function but I need third parameter. Moreover, I will feel happy if anyone can guide me about the best practice of including database in rule. Either we should include only desired model in rule if we need a table in custom validation rule or we should use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB while writing queries in validation rules. I want the following format of passes function

```
public function passes($attribute, $value,$extraparam)
{
    /*Code here*/
}
```

Comment: make an array and pass to the function.

Comment: That would be like some hack but I do not want to use that. I want some proper way to implement that rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass the extra parameter as an argument to the Rule's constructor

```
use App\Rules\Uppercase;

$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', new Uppercase($param)],
]);
```

so you could modify your Rule's class as

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Uppercase implements Rule
{
    protected $extraParam;

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->extraParam = $param;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Access the extra param as $this->extraParam
        return strtoupper($value) === $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. If you can help me regarding db connection, I would be grateful to you.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the database? I didn't quite get what you meant from your question.

Comment: I want to compare something from a database table during this validation. My question is should we load a complete model in this custom rule or should some other way to get this work done. I want to know the best approach for that.

Comment: Both approach would be fine, I would go with Model approach as that would be easier to write and maintain

Comment: loading a whole model would be fine for a single small function?

Comment: What would be the trade-off? and what is the single small function that you are trying to do? I think that would be fine for most of the situations

Comment: I want to check if an id exists in a table and that id should be in specific category eg. id=15 and category=clothing.

Comment: Either case you would be executing the query to check the existence of record, and go with what's best work for you. I don't know of the best approach for such scenario. Thank You!