# Laravel Custom Validation Rule with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, validation, frameworks, laravel-6

I have to validate a field with the input given in another field in custom validation rule.

I have a fields *in1* and *in2*, both are strings and *in1* should start with *in2*.

From the documentation, I can create something like this

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return true;
}
```

Where *attribute* have field name(ex:*in1*) and *value* have value of that field.
How can I pass *in2* to this.

Comment: You could pass the extra parameter as an argument to the Rule's constructor https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272837/12232340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [starts_with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-starts-with) :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'in1' => '...|...', 
   'in2' => 'required_if:in1|starts_with:' . $request->input('in1')
]);
```